# Replace part of an HREF attribute in a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, lightbox

I'm new to jQuery and I need to replace a part of an A HREF attribute in a link. More specifically, a piece of code that will remove the "-h" from "s1600-h" for a lightbox application:

In other words, turn **s1600-h** to **s1600**

Also, do I need to use `$(function()` or `$(document).ready(function()` before the piece of code?

Comment: $(function() is shortcode for the latter

Answer (score 27):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('s1600-h', 's1600');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('a').each(function(){
     this.href = this.href.replace('s1600-h', 's1600');
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old as dirt but, I, being a total noob, was banging my head over a way to change a URL parameter value in a page rendered by SharePoint.  Many of the answers I found were cryptic jquery one-liners that read like Charley Brown's teacher speaks......

Using jquery-3.2.0, and some insight from Bang Dao's post, I yielded this hard fought gem.

**Situation**
The URL containing the parameter I need to change:

`<a class="ms-subtleLink" onclick="GoToLinkOrDialogNewWindow(this);return false;" href="/Site/SubSite/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=27">UserName Text</a>`

**Problem** I needed to change the ID parameter from 27 to 33 in every location on the page.

**Solution**
`$('a.ms-subtleLink').attr('href',function(){this.href = this.href.replace('?ID=27','?ID=33')});`

I realize I did not need to include '?ID=' as part of the replace string.  I only included it to improve the degree of specificity in my match string.

I hope this helps someone with a similar issue some day.

Answer (score -2):

```
var _authorLinkHref = $(this).find('a.temp_form').attr('href',$(this).find('a.temp_form').attr('href').replace('http://', ''));
```